# Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in (0,1)}\left| \frac{1}{nx} \right|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I believe that the above is equal to $\infty$ but I don't have any formal reason why.

Comment: Try and evaluate what $\sup_{x\in (0,1)}|\frac{1}{nx}|$ is for fixed $n>1$.  Note that $|\frac{1}{nx}|=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, because $n$ and $x$ are both positive (we are only considering $0<x<1$).

Comment: For a fixed $n>1$, the $\sup$ would be $\infty$ as the function is unbounded on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Correct.  If this is true for arbitrary $n>1$, then what is the limit of the sequence $\{\infty,\infty,\infty,\infty....\}$?

Comment: Clearly the limit of that sequence is $\infty$

Comment: Exactly.  There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*,$ $\sup\limits_{x\in(0,1)}\frac{1}{nx}=+\infty$ (for all $A>1,$ if you take $x=\frac{1}{A\cdot n}\in(0,1)$ you get $\frac{1}{nx}=\frac{A\cdot n}{n}=A$). Then, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sup\limits_{x\in(0,1)}\frac{1}{nx}=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}+\infty=+\infty.$$